# below is the code to elaborate errore while using streamBuilder Widget in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

```
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                ),
              );
            }
            final message = snapshot.data.documents;//The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Object>'.
            List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
            for (var message in message) {
              final messageText = message.data['text'];
              final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
              final messageWidget =
                  Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
              messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
            }
            return Column(
              children: messageWidgets,
            );
          },
        ),
```

in 11th line of code there is a red line under documents.
"The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'."

when I replace it with docs . the error goes , but another red line showed under a ['text'] and ['sender'] in line 14-15 .

```
              final messageText = message.data['text'];
              final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
```

Comment: Answer to the current problem below. What is the error you get when you fix that? Did you search for that error message already?

Answer (score 0):

The accessor for the documents is now called `docs`, so:

```
final message = snapshot.data.docs;
```

For this type of problem I recommend keeping the reference documentation handy, in this case for the [`QuerySnapshot` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html).